# Export-CSV in Powershell just outputs numbers/length

Tags: powershell, csv, export-csv

I've looked into this issue as others have experienced it as well but I can't really make sense of the issue at hand in order to actually implement any fixes which have been maybe offered up. Here is what I am dealing with specifically.

I am fetching information from an API, parsing through and building my own hashtables which then get pushed into an array. I want to then export that array of hashes as a simple CSV. I have done virtually the same exact setup in another script and it worked without issue, I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here...

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$user    = '*****'
$pass    = ConvertTo-SecureString '******' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred    = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pass
$base    = '*********'
$url     = '*********'
$content = @()
$res     = $null

function fetch_data([String] $path) {
    $req        = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri $path -Method GET
    $global:res = ConvertFrom-Json $req
}

function process_data([String] $arg) {
    fetch_data($arg)

    foreach($i in $res.data) {
       $subscription = @{
            'id'                  = $i.id
            'name'                = $i.name
            'sub_name'            = $i.subscriptionFormReference.name
            'owner_id'            = $i.owner.targetName
            'owner_firstName'     = $i.owner.firstName
            'owner_lastName'      = $i.owner.lastName
            'owner_recipientType' = $i.owner.recipientType    
       }

       foreach($x in $i.data.criteria.data) {
            $sub.lob_name   = $x.name
            $sub.lob_owner  = $x.operator
            $sub.lob_values = $x.value
       }
       $subscription = ConvertTo-Json $subscription
       $global:content.add($subscription)
    }

    if ($res.links.next) {
        $link = $base + $res.links.next
        process_data($link)
    }
}

process_data($url)


Write-Host $content


$content | Export-CSV "\\*******\TEST_CSV.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The outputted file is just a single column with numbers going down as long as the number of objects (hashes I built) that exist in the array above. I'm assuming this is the length of the object in string form maybe and that is what it is recognizing so it may be a formatting issue?

Now, if I print the array to the screen inside the script, I see all the hashtables without issue. The only diff being that they are `{}` rather than `@{}` like in the other script I mentioned earlier which works without issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: your `$content` Var seems to be an array of _hashtables_. it needs to be an array of _PSObjects_ [or PSCusotmObjects]. thry changing this `$subscription = @{` to this `$subscription = [PSCustomObject]@{`.

Comment: ^^^ That did it, thanks! Oversight on my part. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]

Comment: Good catch, @Lee_Dailey - a hashtable is (uselessly) serialized _as a single object_ when passed to `Export-Csv`. vin_Bin87, while that info is a crucial piece of the puzzle, note that there are other problems with your code, notable the extraneous use of `ConvertTo-Json`, which causes your primary symptom.

Comment: @mklement0 - thanks! [*grin*] as you mention, the OP has several other problems in the code. plus, it's overly function-ized. i would likely rewrite it as a straight script and only pull out functions if i saw a serious need for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First and foremost: **Do not call `ConvertTo-Json` on your `$subscription` instances before adding them to `$content`**, because that converts them to a *string*, and passing a string to `Export-Csv` simply exports the `[string]` type's sole property, `.Length` - this is what you saw.
- However, as [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) points out in a comment, even use of the `$subscription` hashtable instances *as-is* doesn't solve the problem, because **a *hashtable* isn't meaningfully serialized when you pass it to `Export-Csv`; a `[pscustomobject]` instance must be used instead**, which (in PSv3+) you can conveniently create by *casting* your hashtable literal to `[pscustomobject]`; that is, use `$subscription = [pscustomobject] @{ ... }` instead of `$subscription = @{ ... }`
- If your code is run in a *script*, **`$global:content` doesn't refer to the *script*'s (top-level) `$content` variable**, but, as the scope specifier suggests, a *global* variable by that name.
- However, even if you targeted the correct variable - with `$script:content` - **calling `.Add()` to grow the array won't work**, because arrays are *fixed-size* collections.
- However, even if you fix that by **using `+=`** instead of `.Add()`, **"growing" an array this way is inefficient**, because PowerShell needs to *recreate* the array every time.

  - Instead, simply **let your `process_data` function *output the `$subscription` objects (hashtables) directly***, which you can either collect in an array that PowerShell *implicitly creates for you* or even pipe directly to `Export-Csv`.

To put it all together:

```
# ...

function process_data([String] $arg) {
  fetch_data $arg # Note: Don't put (...) around function arguments.

  foreach($i in $res.data) {
    # Use a [pscustomobject] cast to create a custom object from the hashtable.
    $subscription = [pscustomobject] @{
          'id'                  = $i.id
          'name'                = $i.name
          'sub_name'            = $i.subscriptionFormReference.name
          'owner_id'            = $i.owner.targetName
          'owner_firstName'     = $i.owner.firstName
          'owner_lastName'      = $i.owner.lastName
          'owner_recipientType' = $i.owner.recipientType    
     }

     foreach($x in $i.data.criteria.data) {
          $subscription.lob_name   = $x.name
          $subscription.lob_owner  = $x.operator
          $subscription.lob_values = $x.value
     }
     # Directly output the $subscription custom object in each iteration.
     # This effectively outputs a collection (array) of objects.
     $subscription
  }

  if ($res.links.next) {
      $link = $base + $res.links.next
      process_data($link)
  }

}

# Call the function and collect the objects in an array.
$content = process_data $url # Note: Don't put (...) around function arguments

Write-Host $content

$content | Export-CSV "\\*******\TEST_CSV.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

`Export-Csv` expects one or more *objects* with properties that'll make up the "columns". You're passing it a list of *strings*.

You can easily create an single-property object from the strings with `Select-Object` before piping to `Export-Csv`:

```
$content |Select-Object @{Name='Json';Expression={$_}} |Export-Csv \\path\to\test_csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

To avoid filling your CSV file with whitespace characters, I'd further suggest you use `ConvertTo-Json` with the `-Compress` parameter switch:

```
   $subscription = ConvertTo-Json $subscription -Compress
```

Which will result in json like:

```
{"id":123,"name":"MyName","sub_name":"MySubName","owner_lastName":"Doe","owner_firstName":"John","owner_recipientType":"Manager","owner_id":"Target Name"}
```

rather than:

```
{
    "id":  123,
    "name":  "MyName",
    "sub_name":  "MySubName",
    "owner_lastName":  "Doe",
    "owner_firstName":  "John",
    "owner_recipientType":  "Manager",
    "owner_id":  "Target Name"
}
```